# How to implement a php Function which accepts a single array of integers and returns the unique integers separated by commas?

Tags: php, unique

How to implement a php Function which accepts a single array of integers and returns the unique integers separated by commas?

Eg: GetUniqueOnes($arr)

$arrr = array(34,54,68,141,151,54,151,54)

should return
34,54,68,141,151,161

Comment: Learning how to format your question is a good thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$string = join(',', array_unique($array));
```

No need for a function;